# Punctuation for sentence ending in quotation marks and a Question mark that is part of a title

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

What is the correct punctuation for a sentence which has quotations with a question mark as part of the title and the title is the end of the sentence?

- Dr. Spencer Johnson discussed the principle in his book "Who Moved My Cheese?".

Does a period go at the end of the sentence, as shown here or not?

Comment: I believe I found the answer in another post regarding declarative quotations with punctuation following...

Comment: The period is not required.